# How to fix Illuminate\Database\QueryException : could not find driver laravel 6

Tags: php

When I run php artisan migrate, I get the error

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : could not find driver
Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDO\Exception::("could not find driver")
      /app/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDO/Exception.php:18
```

Docker php development environment:7.4-fpm-alpine
The pdo_mysql extension pdo_pgsql and
pdo_sqlite are installed.
Help me please.

Comment: make sure PHP- mysql Driver is installed.
one more try, composer require doctrine/dbal

Answer (score 0):

go to "`config`" folder of your project and open `database.php`

and replace with this code

```
'mysql' => [
    'driver' => 'mysql',
    'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
    'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
    'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
    'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
    'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
    'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
    'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
    'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
    'prefix' => '',
    'strict' => true,
    'engine' => 'InnoDB',
],
```

Just install appropriate driver for PHP-MySQL:

```
# default
sudo apt install php-mysql
# for specific version of php (e.g. php7.4)
sudo apt install php7.4-mysql
```

Restart your server:

```
# apache
sudo systemctl restart apache2
# nginx
sudo systemctl restart nginx
```